# Boost, Mutex, class member, shared object member

Tags: c++, boost

I am new to multithread programming, please don't laugh if this seems too simple.

I have a simple class object which has several member variables, e.g.,

```
class XYZ
{
public:
int a;
int b;
...
};
```

xyz is a shared objects among multiple threads, what's the best way to share "a" among multiple threads? For example,

In thread A, I will do something like

```
xyz.a = xyz.a + rand();
```

In thread B, I will do something like

```
xyz.a = xyz.a - rand();
```

I heard about create a mutex as a class member, can someone please give a simple example how to do that.

How can I create a class interface which allows multiple threads to safely access its member?

Comment: I guess I can rephrase the question as "How can I create a class interface which allows multiple threads to safely access its member?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mutex. They can be locked by only one thread simultaneously.

```
class XYZ
{
    int a,b;
    boost::mutex mutex;
}
```

Then use for the thread code

```
void thread(XYZ *xyz)
{
  //....

  // now a member of xyz should be accessed/changed.
  { 
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(xyz->mutex); // lock first the mutex
    // do something with members of xyz
    // ...
  } // mutex automatically freed because lock object destroyed

  //...
 }
```

Comment: johfel, thank you for you reply. Does it automatically lock both a and b? How do I achieve the following,
threadA, only lock a. 
threadB, only lock b. 
Thanks.

Comment: Just use two mutex objects. A mutex does not directly lock itself something. Because it can just be locked by one thread simultaneously, it can be used to control access to anything you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using pointers, you could use `boost::shared_ptr<O>` (where O is your object class of the pointer).

For those ints, you could use: `boost:atomic<int>`